# How to toggle text without jquery in react?

Tags: reactjs, text, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a menu in **react**, that turns into a dropdown menu on smaller devices. I want to **avoid using jQuery**, since as far as I know you should avoid using it in React.

I want the dropdown menu to, well, drop down only if you click a certain thing on the navbar, to reduce the place it would take on the website if it would be always opened on smaller devices. In my case now, the stuff I click is "dropdown. My dropdown menu works, but I want to make my "V" into a "O" when the menu expands, and back to "V" when I close the menu.

I tried to do it with If, but I couldn't figure it out.

JSX:

```
        <div id="container">
            <h1 id="logo">Logo</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem1">Menu option1</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem2">Menu option2</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem3">Menu option3</h1>
            <h1 id="dropdown" onClick={DropDown}>V</h1>
        </div>
```

```
const DropDown = () => {
        if (document.getElementById('dropdown').innerText = 'V'){
            document.getElementById('dropdown').innerText = 'O'
        }
    }
```

The If method I'm using here changes the "dropdown" element to O, but I don't know how to change it back to V.

Comment: I think you should read React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) and follow the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: In React you generally don't directly interact with the DOM.  What you're missing here is essentially the most fundamental part of React... *state*.  You would store a value in state indicating whether the output should be "V" or "O".  The JSX would conditionally output one or the other based on the state value, and the click handler would update the state value.  You are highly encouraged to take a look at some React tutorials to see how state is used.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I actually managed to solve it with state since that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in react you don't manipulate `dom` directly.
you can handle it with `useState` hook. first define the state in the component.

```
const [dropDownText,setDropDownText] = useState("V")
```

so your `DropDown` function should be :

```
const DropDown = () => {
        if (dropDownText=== 'V'){
            setDropDownText("O")
        }else{
            setDropDownText("V")
        }
}
```

and the the element should be

```
<div id="container">
            <h1 id="logo">Logo</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem1">Menu option1</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem2">Menu option2</h1>
            <h1 id="navitem3">Menu option3</h1>
            <h1 id="dropdown" onClick={DropDown}>{dropDownText}</h1>
</div>
```